# Magento 1.8 Set Product Image attributes: Base, Thumbnail, Small_Image

Tags: magento-1.8

I am creating simple product on magento programatically. Product creates successfully with image, but problems is that it does not set attributs Base, Thumbnail, Small_Image for image. What I am doing wrong here?

```
            //Image parameters
            $mediaArray = array('thumbnail', 'small_image', 'image'); 
            $img = $img_subdir.'/fimage.jpeg';


            //create new product
            $newProduct = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
            $newProduct->setAttributeSetId(9)
                       ->setTypeId('simple')
                       ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                       ->setTaxClassId(2)
                       ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'))
                       ->setName('test product #'.mt_rand().'')
                       ->setSku(mt_rand())
                       ->setWeight(25)
                       ->setStatus(1)
                       ->setPrice(25)
                       ->setCategoryIds(explode(',',10))
                       ->setWebsiteIds(explode(',',1))
                       ->setDescription('test')
                       ->setShortDescription('test')
                       ->setMetaTitle('test')
                       ->setMetaKeyword('test')
                       ->setMetaDescription('test')
                       ->setStockData(array(
                                             'manage_stock'=>0,
                                             'min_sale_qty'=>2,
                                             'max_sale_qty'=>10,
                                             'manage_stock'=> 1, 
                                             'is_in_stock'=> 1,
                                             'qty'=> 5,))
                       ->setSetupFee(25)
                       ->addImageToMediaGallery($img, $mediaArray, false, false)
                       ->setsetupCost(25);

                       $newProduct->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this before save should do it:

```
// Add three image sizes to media gallery
$mediaArray = array(
    'thumbnail'   => $putPathHere,
    'small_image' => $putPathHere,
    'image'       => $putPathHere,
);

foreach($mediaArray as $imageType => $fileName) {
    $newProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, $imageType, false);
}
```